# How to display duplicates in SQL only if another column is different?

Tags: sql

So say I have this table:

| Name | Role |
| --- | --- |
| First | Science |
| First | Math |
| First | Science |
| First | Math |
| Second | Science |
| Third | Math |
| Third | Math |

I want to display a column of duplicates for Name/Role ONLY if role is different in each group. So  the final result should be like this:

| Name | Role |
| --- | --- |
| First | Science |
| First | Math |

This is the only person that has a different role for the same name (no matter how many times that specific combination is duplicated). That's why even though Third/Math is also duplicated, it doesn't matter because it's the same combination.

I tried doing a CTE as follows:

```
;with cte as (
Select Name, Role, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by name) as 'rownum1' 
from U.Users
group by u.name, u.role)
```

so then select * from cte where rownum > 1 gets me my names of people that have this issue but it doesn't display the duplicate roles for that user.  Not sure how I should approach it differently?

If I join the CTE table to the original Users table, I also get the single entries.

Comment: What DBMS is this (MySQL. T-SQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc.)? Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: I don't actually know - It's SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the fact that window functions are applied *after* aggregation:

```
select name, role
from (
  select name, role, count(1) over (partition by name) c
  from user_role
  group by name, role
) r
where c > 1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vzRDgBXwYp3VpgNyfn9qzL/0

Comment: I liked this solution and it worked! no complicated joins - but what is the count(1) over partition by name doing, basically counting the sets of usernames in the sub query?

Comment: it's using count as a window function instead of an aggregate function.  after the GROUP BY is processed, you're left with the unique name/role combinations.  count(1) over (partition by name) is counting for each row how many rows exist with that name.  'First' appears twice so both of its rows have a count of 2, which we can then filter in the outer query

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
WITH cte1 as (
SELECT distinct *
FROM 
table1
),
cte2 as 
(
  Select Name, Role, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by name) as rnk 
  from cte1 u 
  group by u.name, u.role
 )
      
SELECT * FROM cte2
where name in
(select name
from cte2
WHERE rnk > 1
group by name
)
```

I used a distinct function to remove any duplicates, then use the ROW_NUMBER() like you to find Names with multiple rows.

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7dda428054680c3cc981c7b3d0a1e223)

Answer (score 0):

So after I posted question I tried this which isn't as elegant as Kurt's answer but  did also work:

```
;with cte as (select name, role, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) rownum

from user_role 
group by name, role)
          
          select distinct user_role.name, user_role.role from user_role 
          join  cte on cte.name=user_role.name and cte.role=user_role.role
          where user_role.name in (select name from cte where rownum =2)
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vzRDgBXwYp3VpgNyfn9qzL/2